# GMapping Odometry Question

Tags: navigation, odometry, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am running GMapping and visualizing the map in Rviz. My fixed frame is set to /map.  I am driving the robot around manually and am generating a fairly accurate map.  My problem is that the link from odom to base_link seems to be moving in the opposite direction.  Base_link remains fixed where at the origin like I expect, but odom moves the opposite direction of the robot.  My /odom ends up being no where near where the map is being generated, but the map still looks fine.  My /odom is publishing that it is at X=3.28, Y=0.44, theta=-11.128 degrees.  However, when I look at its position in RViz for the odom frame, I get X=-0.61441, Y=-0.22086.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9790/gmapping-odometry-question/) by [tyleroar](https://answers.ros.org/users/447/tyleroar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) does a good job of explaining how the various mapping frames interact.

In short, what you're seeing there is what's expected; /odom is the uncorrected odometric information, and will not only be wrong, but will be arbitrarily wrong, given enough time.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-02-19**:
Is /odom should move away from /map when gmapping building a map and robot moving? Thank you~